# My manager data from the promise function doesn't return any value in the loop

Tags: node.js

In data-service.js i have this function `getManager()` that returns a `Promise(pending)` from an initialize function that reads a json file:

```
function getManagers(){
       var managerPromise = initialiaze('path/to/json'):
       return managerPromise;
  }
```

I receive the promise like this in my `server.js`:

```
      var dataservice = require('./data-service.js');
      app.get('/managers', function(req,res){
              dataservice.getManagers.then(function (data){
                data.forEach((element) => {
                     if(element.isManager == true){
                             //here i want to return a json via the res.send where the property 'isManager' is true but it is not working
                   }
               });
          })
    }))
```

Comment: What's not working specifically?

Comment: Using res.send(element) isn't working and also declaring a new array to push the element isn't as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most probably because you are not calling `getManager` function in the following line using ().

```
dataservice.getManagers.then(function (data){
```

Change above to following:

```
dataservice.getManagers().then(function (data){
```

Also don't use `res.send` inside the loop, rather prepare an array of data to send via `res`

```
const managers = [];
data.forEach((element) => {
  if(element.isManager == true){
       managers.push(element);
  }
});
res.send({ manager });
```

Comment: How do I loop through to return data that have a particular property true like 'isManager': true from the data

Comment: @OmolewaStephen see the updated section in my answer.